# Reconnect database in Django

Tags: database, django, connection

I'm testing an import script on a shared web host I just got, but I found that transactions are blocked after running it for 20 minutes or so. I assume this is to avoid overloading the database, but even when I import one item every 1 second, I still run into the problem. To be specific, when I try to save an object I receive the error:

```
DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I've tried to delay for a few hours after this happens, but there is still a block. The only way to resume importing is to completely restart the importing program. Because of this, I reasoned that all I need to do is reconnect to the DB. This might not be true, but it's wroth a try.

So my question is this, how can I disconnect and reconnect the DB connection in Django? Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure no other database errors occur before this one? I usually get this error when a database error has occured but has been ignored by the code.

Comment: Thank you I didn't even notice the duplicate key value error that happened before. Do you want to create an actual answer so I can credit you for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely some other database error occurred before this one, but your code ignored it and went forward with the transaction in a broken state.